# Android Studio: View who is visible only in preview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a simple question. I'm making application in Android Studio and I have got a problem. My application is creating buttons using Java. I want see these buttons in Preview editor, because I want have easier posibility to editing layout. So I made the same buttons in XML, but here is the problem. When I build my app it is showing both buttons! I want see only the buttons creating by Java code and finally here is my question it is possible remove buttons created in XML? I was thinking about tools:.. but I didn't find any usefull tag. Someone have any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `tools:visibility="visible"` and `android:visibility="gone"` together, so they show in the preview, but they're gone when the app is running on a device/emulator.

Comment: But it isn't possible remove them in XML code? When the app is building?

Comment: No, they'll technically still be there when the app is running, but completely invisible and not taking up any space. If you literally want them removed, you'll have to remove them in the java code when the app starts up, so you call 'removeView(child)' on their parent.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, you use `tools:visibility="visible"` in combination with `android:visibility="gone"` to render any view in preview but not in the build.

Using `removeView(someChildElement)` on your layout will remove the element you don't want. AFAIK, the XML code will still be there in the APK, but it isn't there at all in the built APK.

I have no clue **why** you want to show them in preview and not in the finished result. If it is because you want to toggle them manually later, you don't need any XML code. You can also do:

```
someView.setVisibility(GONE)
```

And a quick reference:

- Visible - the view is visible
- Invisible - the view is invisible, but still takes up space
- Gone - the view is invisible and takes up no space

You cannot remove the code from the XML file on build though.

Comment: I want to create an application that will work, and then I want the application to be pretty (The views will be creatre by Java code. I can't see them in preview).
So I think it will not be convenient if I have to build an application when I change one value (I will lose time).